# Implementing Wavelet Transform using Equations

Tags: wavelet

I want to implement Wavelet Transform from the scratch, that mean breaking the wavelet transform into its equations to implement in any Programming language. Matlab Comes with built-in functions to implement Wavelet Transform but It is really hard to understand which processes are exactly involved in the implementation if one wants to develop their own functions.

I know there are Low and High Pass filter involved and the other step called , Down-Sampling but I still have so many doubts on how exactly to combine these filters and samplers to design one's own Wavelet Transform function.

The wavelet tranform block diagram looks like this,

[image]

but there are so many Wavelet transform like Haar, db1, db2 etc. Which wavelet tranform does this blog diagram defines anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [Wavelets for Computer Graphics: A Primer](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/pub/stoll/wavelet1.pdf) a good introduction to the Haar wavelet and its role in image processing.

Answer (score 2):

You should go for the polyphase implementation of wavelet filter bank.
You are referred to the book

[Wavelets and Filter Banks, by Gilbert Strang and Truong Nguyen](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Wavelets_and_Filter_Banks.html?id=Z76N_Ab5pp8C&redir_esc=y)